# How to solve google Blocked app page with Oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I am an frontend developer who is new in using google api.
And it's first time that I call oauth2 api.
But sadly I faced this page.

(
translation: 
Blocked app.
App tried to access important information on your account. Google blocked this access to protect your account
If you are developer, request certification about the app to google
)

[image]

What I tried before I faced this page:

1. adding People API
2. adding redirection uri
3. putting client_id when I call oauth api 
   (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth)

When this page showed: I faced this page when I choosed the account (red square)

[image]

My senior said it showed because I called too much.
Is it possible that this page showed because of much calling API?

Comment: your app needs to be verified.   This is not a quota error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.
There was a scope trouble.
Because deprecated Contacts API's scope is same as one of People API's scopes, scopes were conflicted.
I made a new console project to solve it.
Now, I use People API well.